# Slow connecting to spring boot application deployed on vps from mobile

Tags: java, spring-boot, vps

My spring boot v2.2.0 app deployed on vps Centos 7, when i opening on laptop it has no problems and opens fast, but if i open it from mobile phone opens take about 2-5 minutes. 
I start my application like: java -jar myapp.jar&

Start with -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom option changes nothing
Add tomcat-native library changes nothing too

Comment: Are you on the same network on your mobile phone? Is your app so heavy, that your computer runs it fine, but your phone is choking on it?

Comment: I tried too open from the same network, and from other network, still the same. Jar file about 45mb.

Comment: The jar file size doesn't really tell much, except how much space it takes on the server. You should put plenty of logging to find out where the time is taken, for example does the client connect and then it takes 2-5 minutes to get the data, or does it take 2-5 before the client even connects. Of course you can also test with other phones and tablets if you have, since it seems to be client related.

Comment: Thank you, i had problem with one of js.